# How to generate system alias in /iwfnd/maint_service?

Tags: service, sapui5, sap-gateway

I have following problem:

I created an app  and the according oData in frontend system. Everything worked fine. Then I was taught, that this was not correct and I have to create the oData in backend system.

So I made this. I created just the same oData in backend system, created another service for the new oData in transaction /iwfnd/maint_service in frontend system, changed the data source in the manifest of my app, and everything seemed to work fine. To add the app to the launchpad I needed one (or two?) more services in transaction SICF (paths sap/bc/bsp/sap and sap/bc/ui5_ui5/sap). Those were generated automatically for my "frontend-oData". As those weren't generated automatically in frontend system for my new "backend-oData", I added them manually. This seemed to work as well. So I transported everything into quality system (the app from WebIDE to SAP was transported as "updating an already existing application").

And now my problem:

Yesterday after transporting my app ran perfectly in just updated version. Today I get an error in quality system, that says:
"No systemalias for service 'ZEXAMPLE_SRV_0001' and user 'USER1234' found" (I translated this error message from german). This error is new to me and I did not have this before. The settings for my "frontend-oData" were different ones (no systemalias & service processing mode = "Co-deployed only") and they were generated automatically.

Now for my "backend-oData" in development system there is the setting "Routing-based" and the correct systemalias is maintained and the app runs perfectly there.  But in quality system there is no systemalias maintained. So I transported the systemalias from development system to quality system, but that didn't work, because the systemalias has to be a different one in quality system.

I tried to make exact the same settings in quality system for my "backend-oData" as the "frontend-oData" has, but then in /IWFND/ERROR_LOG I get the message "No service for namenspace /SAP/, Name ZEXAMPLE_SRV, Version 0001 found."

So can anyone tell me the secret which step I need to do, that everything runs correctly again? I am desperated by now.

Many thanks and best regards

Comment: Did you activate the service in transaction SICF?

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. Yes I did so. I had to do this in quality system after transport.

Answer (score 1):

In your dev system open transaction `/IWFND/MAINT_SERVICE` and select the service in the service catalogue.

You should see the system aliases in the bottom right:

[image]

Press on *Customizing* and in the following view switch to edit mode:

[image]

As soon as you are in edit mode, you can select *Table view > Transport*. It will ask you to select an existing transport or to create a new one.

Two buttons will appear in the customizing view. *Add to transport* and *Remove from transport*.

[image]

Select the system alias row from the table and press *Add to transport*.

**Now press save!!! Otherwise the alias will not be part of the transport. It's only "put on hold" when you press "Add to transport". Press save!!!**

Move the transport to your next system (and eventually into production) if you want to use your OData service in other systems.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I did exactly this and then I had the systemalias from devolpment system in quality system. But this was not correct, because for each system (dev, qual, prod) there should be maintained an own special systemalias. I got this error message in /iwfnd/error_log in quality system: "RFC Error: RFC-Destination DEVCLNT100_DIA does not exist." (original: RFC Error: RFC-Destination DEVCLNT100_DIA existiert nicht.). In development system everything runs with this setting without errors.

Comment: Maybe you can talk to your base admins. I think it's best practice if the alias is the same across all systems (so for example LOCAL always points to your current system). Only the RFC destination should change in all the servers (Alias and Destination are not the same!)

Comment: If the alias will not be changed then your only other option (I think) is to do the above steps in each system.

Comment: Ok, many thanks. I will do so. If I can figure out any solution from basis admins, I will let you know :)